# Application_Error() is being called twice when any error occurs(unhanded Exception occurs)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I my C#.net mvc application Application_Error() is being called twice whenever any error occurs.

code of Application_Error() is:

```
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
                //var currentController = " ";
                //var currentAction = " ";
                string currentController;
                string currentAction;
                var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
                currentController = "";
                currentAction = "";
                if (currentRouteData != null)
                {
                    if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
                    {
                        currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                    }

                    if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
                    {
                        currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                var ex = Server.GetLastError();
                var controller = new ErrorController();
                var routeData = new RouteData();
                var action = "Error";

                if (ex is HttpException)
                {
                    var httpEx = ex as HttpException;

                    switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode())
                    {
                        case 400:
                            action = "BadRequest";
                            break;

                        case 401:
                            action = "Unauthorized";
                            break;

                        case 403:
                            action = "Forbidden";
                            break;

                        case 404:
                            action = "NotFound";
                            break;

                        case 408:
                            action = "RequestTimeout";
                            break;

                        case 500:
                            action = "InternalServerError";
                            break;

                        case 502:
                            action = "BadGateway";
                            break;

                        case 503:
                            action = "ServiceUnavailable";
                            break;

                        case 504:
                            action = "GatewayTimeout";
                            break;
                    }
                }

                httpContext.ClearError();
                httpContext.Response.Clear();
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
                httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

               routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
              routeData.Values["action"] = action;

                controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);

                ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your browser is sending an automatic request to the `/favicon.ico` file on the error page, which icon you forgot to include in your application and respectively the Application_Error event is triggered a second time for the 404. You could see more details about the request by putting a breakpoint in the Application_Error method and analyzing the value of:

```
httpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

I put my 2¢ that you will see something like `http://localhost:1234/favicon.ico`.